# Create a background of rotating shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a container with a background of rotating shapes. Right now they're inserted randomly inside the container, that's desirable but not necessary. They do have to be inside of the container and not collide with each other.

I've searched for an explanation on how to do this and also tried a lot of things but can't seem to get anything to work. Any advice or technique to accomplish this is highly appreciated!

This is my goal:

[image]

And this is what I've got right now:

```
 var container = document.getElementById('container');

 for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   var squarePositionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
   var squarePositionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

   var circlePositionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
   var circlePositionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80);

   var square = document.createElement('div');
   square.className = 'square';
   square.innerHTML = '';
   square.style.top = squarePositionY + 'px';
   square.style.left = squarePositionX + 'px';
   container.appendChild(square);

   var circle = document.createElement('div');
   circle.className = 'circle';
   circle.innerHTML = '';
   circle.style.top = circlePositionY + 'px';
   circle.style.left = circlePositionX + 'px';
   container.appendChild(circle);
 }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pistevw/yaygwct7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first step is to subtract the width and height of the shape from their possible position:

`var squarePositionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerWidth - squareWidth));`

then you'll have to check if that space is taken, to check this you can

1. iterate through all the elements and ask what their size and position is
2. save the size and position of every element

in the snippet below I iterated through all of the elements and made a function `collide()`to check if they are colliding

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
var containerHeight = container.clientHeight;

var shapeDiameter = 15;
var containerPadding = 2.5;

var shapes = ["square", "circle", "triangle"];
var allShapes;

var amount = 200;
var escape = amount * 100;
var k = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  k++;
  var shapePositionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerWidth - shapeDiameter)) + containerPadding;
  var shapePositionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerHeight - shapeDiameter)) + containerPadding;
  var shapeRotation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

  var shape = document.createElement('div');
  shape.className = shapes[i % 3];
  shape.innerHTML = '';
  shape.style.top = shapePositionY + 'px';
  shape.style.left = shapePositionX + 'px';
  shape.style.transform = "rotate(" + shapeRotation + "deg)";
  container.appendChild(shape);

  allShapes = container.children;
  if (i > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < allShapes.length - 1; j++) {
      if (collide(allShapes[j], allShapes[allShapes.length - 1])) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
  if (k >= escape) {
    alert("capped at " + i);
    i = amount;
  }
}

function collide(obj1, obj2) {
  var shapeDiameter1, shapeDiameter2;
  if(obj1.className == "square"){
    shapeDiameter1 = 15;
  }else if(obj1.className == "circle"){
    shapeDiameter1 = 10.5;
  }else if(obj1.className == "triangle"){
    shapeDiameter1 = 11.5;
  }
  if(obj2.className == "square"){
    shapeDiameter2 = 16;
  }else if(obj2.className == "circle"){
    shapeDiameter2 = 11;
  }else if(obj2.className == "triangle"){
    shapeDiameter2 = 12;
  }
  
  
  var myleft = parseInt(obj1.style.left, 10);
  var myright = myleft + shapeDiameter1;
  var mytop = parseInt(obj1.style.top, 10);
  var mybottom = mytop + shapeDiameter1;
  var otherleft = parseInt(obj2.style.left, 10);
  var otherright = otherleft + shapeDiameter2;
  var othertop = parseInt(obj2.style.top, 10);
  var otherbottom = othertop + shapeDiameter2;
  var collide = true;
  if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
    collide = false;
  }
  return collide;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.square {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid Gainsboro;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.circle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid Gainsboro;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 8.7px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent Gainsboro transparent;
  position: absolute;
}
/*
.square:before,
.circle:before,
.triangle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.square:before {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: -3.5px;
  left: -3.5px;
}

.circle:before {
  width: 10.5px;
  height: 10.5px;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
}

.triangle:before {
  width: 11.5px;
  height: 11.5px;
  left: -5.5px;
  top: 0px;
}*/
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I've updated the fiddle with subtraction of width and height of a shape (as example, the square). But I don't think I did it all right. And I've added iteration to check size and position. I'm not sure how I could save it though. Could I save it and then ask if this position has a shape then put it somewhere else? Happy for all help and explanations :)